# Adding Documents to Solr by using Java Client API is failed

Tags: java, apache, api, solr

I have the code to add document to Solr. I tested it in Both Solr 6.6.2 and Solr 7.2.1 and failed.

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient; 
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException; 
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient; 
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument; 

public class AddingDocument { 
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception { 


String urlString ="http://localhost:8983/solr/Solr_example";
     SolrClient Solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();   

      //Preparing the Solr document 
      SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument(); 

      //Adding fields to the document 
      doc.addField("id", "007"); 
      doc.addField("name", "James Bond"); 
      doc.addField("age","45"); 
      doc.addField("addr","England"); 

      //Adding the document to Solr 
      Solr.add(doc);         

      //Saving the changes 
      Solr.commit(); 
      System.out.println("Documents added"); 
   } 
}
```

The compilation is successful like below.

javac -cp .:/opt/solr/solr-6.6.2/dist/solr-solrj-6.6.2.jar AddingDocument.java

However, when I run it, it gave me some errors message confused.

java -cp .:/opt/solr/solr-6.6.2/dist/solr-solrj-6.6.2.jar AddingDocument

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/Header
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$Builder.build(HttpSolrClient.java:892)
    at AddingDocument.main(AddingDocument.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.Header
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

What is wrong with it? Is this urlString correct?

Any help is appreciated!

After adding jar file, the compiling is in success.

javac -cp .:/opt/solr/solr-6.6.2/dist/*:/opt/solr/solr-6.6.2/dist/solrj-lib/*   AddingDocument.java

The doc is added into solr. However, there are some error message about slf4j which is as below.

java -cp .:/opt/solr/solr-6.6.2/dist/*:/opt/solr/solr-6.6.2/dist/solrj-lib/*   AddingDocument

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Documents added

Comment: You're missing the httpcore.jar file, add it to classpath on your console. You'll need more than just the single solrj jar. Any "NoClassDefFoundError" is usually a missing jar file.

Comment: javac -cp .:/opt/solr/solr-6.6.2/dist/*:/opt/solr/solr-6.6.2/dist/solrj-lib/*   AddingDocument.java    is used and compiling has no problem. However, the running has some problem as below.

Comment: SLF4J error disappeared after copy slf4j-nop-1.7.25.jar file into /opt/solr/solr-6.6.2/dist/ folder. MatsLindh, Thank you!